# How to specify output directory of CSS file in scssphp

Tags: sass, redux-framework

I'm using Redux Framework and SASS. I've checked the http://leafo.net/scssphp/docs/ documentation, but I can't seem to find any mention of output css file directory mentions. And also how do I pass the Redux variables(taken from options field) to scss(_variables.scss) file and update the output css when I update of Redux Framework options from admin options menu. Thanks in advance.